# Formatting DateTime error

Tags: c#

I have string of the following format:

```
29-Feb-17 03.36.15.1902 PM
```

and I am trying to convert it into a DateTime object with the following code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(request.DispatchTime, "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.ffff tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But getting the error:

```
The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.
```

Comment: That format is not supported by the `GregorianCalendar` class as the error states. `29-Feb-17` is a poor format as the `17` is assumed, we don't know if you mean `1917` or `2017`, so it's not supported in general for `DateTime` as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
29-Feb-17
```

Is not an existing `datetime`. Thus the corresponding library cant resolve it

Comment: Shouldn't that rather be a comment?

Comment: @lokusking: if this is a valid question this is a valid answer. There is no way to fix it

Comment: @TimSchmelter There is a way to fix it, that's for OP to use a proper date format in their string.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: what date format supports an invalid date?

Comment: @TimSchmelter *"that's for OP to use a proper date format in their string"* I'm saying they need to change their date format of their "29-Feb-17 03.36.15.1902 PM" date string. Along with updating the format string to reflect that.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: that is not the date-format but the date-string. Yes, he should fix the source of this probably invalid date. But it doesn't help to change the format-string. Btw, there are other calendars than the `GregorianCalendar`. Maybe that is causing this issue

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think you misread my last comment. I stated that both the date-string and format-string need to be updated.